# How can I restore an uncommited file between branches?

Tags: git

The situation is:

```
        branch2
        /
       /
master
       \
        \
       branch1
```

I created a file (`aaaa.py`) in branch1, but I didn't commit it. Later I changed to branch2 and I did some changes in the file (`aaaa.py`) and I committed it in this branch (branch2) but now I want to restore the file (`aaaa.py`) like it was at branch1 before it was changed.

IMPORTANT: Now `aaaa.py` doesn't exist in branch1 because I didn't commit it in that branch.

How I can do it?

Comment: It won't existing in branch1 since it was never committed

Answer (score 0):

If you are on branch2 and want to restore aaa.py as it is in branch1, you can do

```
git checkout branch1 -- path/to/aaaa.py
```

Comment: The problem is that the file aaaa.py doesn't exist in branch1 becose when I commited it on branch2 it disappeared